# Making sure that a pair of functions is executed even if C-g is pressed in the middle

Tags: keystrokes, inhibit

Based on the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting.html#Quitting), I am trying the following:

```
(let ((inhibit-quit t))
    (my-fun)
    (y-or-n-p "Prompt")
    (cancel-effects-of-my-fun))
```

Here, `my-fun` performs changes to configuration and `cancel-effects-of-my-fun` restores the configuration to its original state. I need to make sure that `(cancel-effects-of-my-fun)` is evaluated even if the user presses `C-g` during the evaluation of `(y-or-n-p "Prompt")`. The code above does not do the job. In fact, even setting `inhibit-quit` globally does not have any effect. I tried `(setq quit-flag nil)`, but that did not make a difference either. What am I missing? Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: The doc-string for `unwind-protect` looks interesting and I see it a lot in the built-in code, but I haven't played with it myself.

Comment: `unwind-protect` did exactly what I needed!

Comment: Due to magic, `y-or-n-p` signals a `quit` error in case the user presses `C-g`, rather then setting `quit-flag` like the ordinary `C-g` at top-level.  That's why inhibiting it has no effect, it is not set anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based upon the comment of the original poster underneath the question, the function `unwind-protect` achieves the desired behavior.  The doc-string and printout of the `*Help*` buffer for `describe-function` is as follows:

```
unwind-protect is a special form in `eval.c'.

(unwind-protect BODYFORM UNWINDFORMS...)

Do BODYFORM, protecting with UNWINDFORMS.
If BODYFORM completes normally, its value is returned
after executing the UNWINDFORMS.
If BODYFORM exits nonlocally, the UNWINDFORMS are executed anyway.
```